# Memcache not working with Laravel but it's working when using it directly

Tags: laravel

I have memcached set up on my server.

If I use the following code -

```
$meminstance = new Memcached();

$meminstance->addServer("127.0.0.1", 11211);
$meminstance->setOption(Memcached::OPT_BINARY_PROTOCOL, true);
$meminstance->setSaslAuthData("user", "pass");
$result = $meminstance->get("test");

if ($result) {
    echo $result;
} else {
    echo "No matching key found.  Refresh the browser to add it!";
    $meminstance->set("test", "Successfully retrieved the data!") or die("Couldn't save anything to memcached...");
}
```

then everything works perfectly.

However, if I set the same settings via laravel then the cache does not work at all. When I check debug bar, the cache keeps missing.

.env

```
MEMCACHED_USERNAME=user
MEMCACHED_PASSWORD=pass
MEMCACHED_HOST=127.0.0.1
MEMCACHED_PORT=11211
```

config/cache.php

```
        'memcached' => [
            'driver' => 'memcached',
            'persistent_id' => env('MEMCACHED_PERSISTENT_ID', 1),
            'sasl' => [
                env('MEMCACHED_USERNAME'),
                env('MEMCACHED_PASSWORD'),
            ],
            'options' => [
                // Memcached::OPT_CONNECT_TIMEOUT  => 2000,
                //Memcached::OPT_BINARY_PROTOCOL => true,
            ],
            'servers' => [
                [
                    'host' => env('MEMCACHED_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
                    'port' => env('MEMCACHED_PORT', 11211),
                    'weight' => 100,
                ],
            ],
        ],
```

What can be the cause of this? I've noticed that if I enter the incorrect credentials or server details, no error appears. Is it possible that Laravel just isn't communicating with the memcached server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to fix it by enabling UDP in memcached.

`sudo nano /etc/memcached.conf`

and remove the line

`-U 0`